# Rails3 nested layout and partials passing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, nested, partial, link-to

Hey,
I'm working on a page having a nested layout. first I have the applicationlayout with my "mainmenu" now I want to add a second menu only on this page. I got this working via

```
<% render :partial => "mypartial", :layout => 'navigation' %>
```

this adds my second navigation to the form and renders a partial.

At this point I try to distinguish between two different partials. so my file looks like this

```
<% if :passed_text == "page1" %>
  <%= render :partial => "mypartial1", :layout => 'navigation' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => "mypartial2", :layout => 'navigation' %>
<% end %>
```

my navigation is as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Mypartial1", partial_path, :passed_text => :page1 %>
<%= link_to "Mypartial2", partial_path, :passed_text => :page2 %>
<%= yield %>
```

but it ignores my parameters. I guess I'm missing something basic, but all this is new to me.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I found an answer:

first I have to check for:

```
params[:passed_text]
```

instead of :passed_text

secondly passing the parameters has to be in brackets

```
partial_path( :passed_text => :page1)
```

this works fine